# Why are distinct Type objects being generated by Clang's parser for the same type?

Tags: c++, types, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following snippet that I'm parsing using Clang's API for a tool I'm writing:

```
namespace NS
{
    struct X
    {
    };
}

struct Y
{
    NS::X foo();
};
```

[I use a (type that derives from) `RecursiveASTVisitor` to visit the AST](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html). When the `VisitCXXRecordDecl()` function is invoked, I can get a pointer to the declared `Type` object:

```
bool VisitCXXRecordDecl(CXXRecordDecl* const decl)
{
    auto declared_type = decl->getTypeForDecl();
    // ...
}
```

Similarly, when the `VisitCXXMethodDecl()` function is invoked, I can get a pointer to the function's return `Type` like so:

```
bool VisitCXXMethodDecl(CXXMethodDecl* const func) 
{
    auto return_type = func->getReturnType().getTypePtr();
    // ...
}
```

To my surprise, the variables `declared_type` and `return_type` in the two functions above do not point to the same `Type` object.

Now I do know about *canonical types*, and indeed if I write the following inside `VisitCXXMethodDecl()` I will get a pointer to the same `Type` object `declared_type` points to:

```
auto canonical_type = return_type->getCanonicalTypeInternal().getTypePtr();
// Now `canonical_type` holds a pointer to the same Type object as the
// `declared_type` variable inside VisitCXXRecordDecl().
```

However, I thought a type has a canonical type different from itself only when type aliases are involved (at least this is what I gather from [the Doxygen docs](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html) and [the CFE Internals Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#canonical-types)). I'm not sure what is the reason why two `Type` objects are created here, which makes me believe I did not understand the role of `Type` objects and canonical types in Clang's design.

Comment: clang may be trying to remember that the type was spelled NS::X, as opposed to, for instance, X (that would be found thanks to a using directive). Why not look into that non-canonical type more closely (possibly in a debugger) to see what information it is storing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is due to how clang interprets the return type of your function

```
NS::X foo();
^^^^^
```

[According to the documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ElaboratedType.html#details), an `ElaboratedType`

> represents a type that was referred to using an elaborated type keyword, e.g., struct S, or via a qualified name, e.g., N::M::type, or both.

This means the `declared_type` points to a `RecordType` object, but that `return_type` actually points to an `ElaboratedType`.

If you had passed this source code to the visitor:

```
namespace NS
{
    struct X
    {
    };
}

using namespace NS;
// struct NS::X -> heavily sugar'd
// NS::X -> sugar'd
// struct X -> sugar'd
// X -> not sugar'd
struct Y
{
    X foo();
};
```

you'd have received the same address for all three pointers.

This distinction is by design and unrelated to the symbol's visibility.